# CUDA - convert RGB image to Grayscale

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, cuda, gpu

I am starting to learn CUDA GPU programming from Udacity video course (course is 2 yrs old). I am using **CUDA 5.5 with Visual Studio Express 2012** (students edition, so not all features of CUDA debugging is not available) on **Nvidia GeForce GT 630M GPU**.

Just implemented some vector addition and other simple operations.

Now I am trying to **convert a RGB image to Grayscale**. I am reading image with help of OpenCV. (Anyway I failed whatever methods I tried. That is why I am here)

Below is my .cpp file : https://gist.github.com/abidrahmank/7020863

Below is my .cu file : https://gist.github.com/abidrahmank/7020910

My input image is a simple 64x64 color image (Actually I used 512x512 image first, didn't work, so brought down to 64x64 to check if that is the problem. It doesn't seem so)

**Problem**

**My output image of CUDA implementation is a white image**. All value 255. Somewhere here and there, there are some gray pixels, may be less than 1%. Remaining everything is white.

**What I tried:**

For three days, I tried following things:

1. I thought problem may be due image size, so that number of threads may not be optimal or something like that, So reduced image size. Still same result.
2. I tried a similar example, created a 64x64 array. Take its two pixels at a time, and find the square of their sums, and it worked fine. Here is the code : https://gist.github.com/abidrahmank/7021023
3. Started checking data one-by-one at each stage. Input image just before loading to GPU is fine. **But input data, when I checked inside kernel, is always 255.** (Check [line 14 here](https://gist.github.com/abidrahmank/7020910#file-rgb2gray_cuda-cu-L14))
4. Finally I set all GPU data to zero using `CudaMemset` and checked input data inside kernel, it is still 255.

So I don't have any other option to do other asking at StackOverflow.

**Can anyone tell me what is the mistake I am making?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kernel signature says:

```
__global__ void kernel(unsigned char* d_in, unsigned char* d_out)
```

But you call it like:

```
kernel<<<rows,cols>>>(d_out, d_in);
```

Which one is **in** and which one is **out**?

Having done quite a bit of CUDA programming in the past, I would strongly recommend that you use [Thrust](http://thrust.github.io/) instead of hand-crafting kernels. Even `thrust::for_each` is hard to beat with raw kernels.

Comment: Oh my god.... How did I miss that? Corrected it and working fine. Wasted three days of my life. Thank you so much for the help. Well, I just started CUDA, don't know much about ``Thrust``. Anyway I will check it.

Comment: Thrust is shipped with CUDA nowadays (although it supports backends other than CUDA). It provides parallel implementations of most STL algorithms, plus a bunch of very useful algorithms. It puts Microsoft's PPL and Intel's TBB to shame. I can't possibly write enough praises to Thrust in these comments, trust me.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the parameter issue indicated by DanielKO, you also have problems on thread/block settings.

Since you've already treat your 2-D image as a 1-D array, here's a good example showing how to set thread/block for data with arbitrary size.

https://developer.nvidia.com/content/easy-introduction-cuda-c-and-c

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the link. I just started it and still breaking head on the concepts like thread, block etc. So in this particular task, I just wanted to make it work first. All other optimizations and worries are left for future.  @DanielKO's answer solved my problem so I have to accept his answer.

Comment: Working out proper index computation, kernel launch configuration, etc, can be a messy task. As I mentioned, Thrust can do it all for you (it has heuristics to figure out the best launch configuration for your GPU, and can give you indices through counting iterators).